# How to upload image in phonegp frontend and save to django backend using ajax

Tags: javascript, python, django, cordova

I want o upload the image in front-end phone-gap and send that image to django backend and save that image in database.

Can anyone give me the reference how to do his. I tried but not able to do this. Please guide me how to do this.

Thanks a lot,,,,,,

Comment: Hello @Gaurav Wagh, what exactly have you tried and what was not working? We would love to help, given that you provide more details.

Comment: I am trying to send the image from frontend to django backend and save that image in to the database. But in html frontend i dont know how to upload the image. is it possible to send the path only and get that image in backend.?

Comment: http://www.udemy.com/blog/ajax-image-upload/

Comment: In the simplest case (e.g. a form with file path on frontend) forms a POST request with the image data. On Django side - you have to simply store that data in a file (e.g. in your MEDIA directory) and add an appropriate path to the database.

Comment: Can you give me the simple example for this? Mention this in answer.

Comment: How about https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/ ?